# How to run ruby files in sublime-text-2

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, sublimetext2

When i press ctrl+b to run simple code such as:

```
puts "asdasd"
```

the result is blank field. Ruby path is /home/yukke/.rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby and ruby -v => ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux].

so I tried to change Ruby.sublime-build to

```
{
    "cmd": ["/home/yukke/.rvm/rubies/default/bin/ruby", "-u","$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

But it didn't change anything.
Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: The "build" feature can only display up to 4 errors. It isn't meant to display full input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute Ruby code in sublime text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410158/execute-ruby-code-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Make sure  ruby is in the PATH (for windows) of your operating system. By default Submlime has a Ruby build system and it works out of the box. You need to fix in the operating system path, it appears that sublime could not find the ruby executable.

Comment: Robert K, of course i saved the file. 
Sundar, my OS is ubuntu.
Yesterday i reinstall ubuntu, rwm, ruby and sublime. But it still don't works..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, take out the "-u", and use rvm

```
"cmd": ["/home/yukke/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "$file"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the file before it will work.  It's not nearly as nice as TextMate's <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, and doesn't work in the same way, if that was what you were expecting.