# Ruby 1.9.3 - cannot load such file for some reason

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-1.9

Ruby 1.9.3
Very simple code and very simple question I can't deal with:

```
gem list --local
nokogiri (1.5.5)

gem q --local
nokogiri (1.5.5)
```

But  a ruby script (not Rails):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML("some valid xml....")
```

gives me

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/alex/test.rb:3:in `<main>'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

I'm aware that it's not necessary to use `require 'rubygems'`, but even when I do that, it does not work either.

```
gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
     - /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/


gem which nokogiri
/home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri.rb
```

Comment: What OS are you using, and how are you running ruby (e.g. rbenv?).  I'm running `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410)` on OS X and the above works perfectly.

Comment: That's ubuntu 12. I'm running that in Sublime text2. Other ruby scripts work perfectly, thus this issue is not because of Sublime Text.

Comment: Would you mind adding the output of `gem environment`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are running this from Sublime Text?

Comment: I mean that I'm running that from Sublime Text. Exactly.

Comment: if you're using rvm, are you sure you are installing that gem in the right gemset? If yes, are you running your script in that gemset?

Comment: I use rvm. I don't know if I installed nokogiri correctly or not. I just installed it like I always do: gem install nokogiri. How do I check that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because of the wrong  Sublime Text build system. The right one is here [How to run ruby files in sublime-text-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851566/how-to-run-ruby-files-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score -2):

you need to add Nokogiri to the Gemfile (with the line gem 'nokogiri').

Comment: I did. This is not a Rails app.

Comment: bundler also exists outside rails. also check RVM gemsets

Comment: -1 Should not assume Bundler is being used. Should ask in comments and then answer accordingly.

Comment: Bundler is installed or not was asked in comments only. Its not visible for you Mr. @Charles Caldwell ?

Comment: I meant in the comments to the question. Not the comments to an answer that already made the assumption.