# How to run a Ruby script in Sublime Text 2 from project root

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

I have a Ruby project and I'd like to run the scripts directly from Sublime Text in place of having to run them in the terminal. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS if that matters at all.

From the terminal I need to be located in the project root to make the script work:

```
$ ruby path/to/file/file.rb
```

If I try to run it from where the file is located it fails because they are requiring files from various places in the project.

If I run the script in Sublime Text (Ctrl + Shift + B) it fails the same way as I'm running it from the file location.

How do I do this? I suspect this can be solved with a [custom build](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) but I've been unsuccessful until now. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A build file like this might meet your requirements:

```
{
  "working_dir": "/full/path/to/project/root/",
  "cmd": ["/full/path/to/ruby/", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

Comment: Because the `$file` parameter is the full path to the file, not relative to project root.

Comment: Which is exactly what you requested in your OP:  

"From the terminal I need to be located in the project root to make the script work:

`$ ruby path/to/file/file.rb`"

Comment: Notice there isn't a slash in the beginning :) like `$ ruby /path/...` but perhaps that's not clear enough.

Comment: Ooohh ... the full path to Ruby I had wasn't working - fixed it and now it's working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Hardcoding the path in the build makes this unportable, but there's the template variable `${project_path}` which is always the root directory of the current project.

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your scripts you might want to look into using [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control%20Package%20Control) and the [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL%20SublimeREPL%20package.) Package.

SublimeREPL allows you to have a Ruby Interpreter in a separate tab or window in SublimeText. Running CMD + Shift + B has never been very reliable in SublimeText for Ruby code anyways.

Also, similar answer to similar question: [Execute Ruby code in sublime text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410158/execute-ruby-code-in-sublime-text-2?rq=1)

Comment: Using Pry within ST2 is not what the OP wants.  

"Running CMD + Shift + B has never been very reliable in SublimeText for Ruby code anyways."  -- according to whom?  I have no problem running Ruby from ST2.