# How to run ruby on terminal using sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not even sure if this question is right.

I'm doing a ruby tutorial on the following link
www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dji9ALCgfpM

And he writes code on sublime, and the ran code is shown on terminal. 
I used to do berry thing on integrative ruby, irb. 
What's the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute Ruby code in sublime text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410158/execute-ruby-code-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 6):

You have two main options:

The first option is to run the Ruby code in your terminal. Save your Ruby file as somename.rb. In your terminal, navigate to the directory you saved it in, and then simply run it with

```
ruby somename.rb
```

It should then run nicely. Do make sure you have Ruby installed on your system first, otherwise look [here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/)

Alternatively you can run it right there in Sublime Text. Make sure you're in Ruby mode by clicking on the language selector in the bottom-right corner of the screen.

Also - in the top menu go to Tools -> Build System -> Ruby

From then on, you can run it right there in Sublime by pressing Tools -> Build, or using the CTRL-B hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no connection with terminal and sublime**. Sublime is a text editor, there is an option to build your program there(sublime) using `ctrl + b`, but if you are getting user input at run time then the file just gets build but doesn't run.

If you want to run your ruby file in terminal:

Write your code in sublime or any other text editors and save the file with extension (.rb). In terminal , if you have installed ruby, type `irb filename.rb`. But before that check the current directory is set to the file location. If not change directory using cd command that is `cd filepath`.

Running a sample ruby file in terminal using irb:
[image: Running a sample ruby file in terminal using irb]

Running a sample ruby file in sublime:
[image: Running in sublime]

Comment: how does one run the sample ruby file in sublime?

Answer (score 0):

You create your Ruby program in a file :

```
my_first_ruby_program.rb
```

You put some content in it:

```
puts "Hello world"
```

Then you execute your program by launching it in the console (assuming you're in the same directory as the file/ruby program you have created):

```
ruby my_first_program.rb
```

irb is an interactive shell, it's useful for testing some short programs or lines of code. When you want to make a "full" program/script you want to save it into a file. Then you can execute it.

Some links:

[Make your first ruby file (middle of the post)](http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-ruby/)

[More about IRB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html)

learn more about ruby and ror:

[Ruby tutorial](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0)

[Rails tutorial](http://railsforzombies.org/)

Comment: So I save sublime text in a file, and run that on terminal using "ruby "keyword?

Comment: Yes absolutely, this is what the guy in video is doing, you can see the first line of the command shell is always something like "ruby my_file.rb"

Comment: If you're looking for something more automated maybe there are sublime plugins that can do that for you. Some kind of guard/auto-reload. You can also use (cmd+b or ctrl+b) in sublime to build it. If ruby is selected as your build language (in tools) you should get the result in the sublime console directly.

Comment: The idea is that you tell the terminal that you want to run a program named ruby.  It will search some folder where all your programs are and find the program ruby. Now it sees you have some text following it. It will push that text into the executed ruby program as a run parameter. Now the ruby program will know it self what to do. In case you tell it a file name, it will compile the file and then run it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, when do I use interactive ruby? I'm a noob in ruby, thinking to learn it during summer break. How did you guys learn ruby?is it necessarily to learn ruby to do Ruby on Rails?

Comment: IRB is really useful for testing short parts of code, an expression ... If there's a lot of logic put it in a file it's gonna be more readable. I added two more links to tutorials, but I think you should post another question for the learning path. If the answer helped you consider validating it an voting up.