# What is wrong with this piece of code(trivial)

Tags: ruby

This is a very trivial function I wrote to read text as a prompt. It doesn't work but doesn't give me errors either. I've tried all modifications I can think if to get it to work, but to no avail.

Code:

```
def prompt(query="")
    print (query) #I also tried 'print"#{query}"   
    var = gets()  
    return var
end

name = prompt("Input your name:")    
puts"#{name}"
```

Nothing happens. This has frustrated me, that I couldn't do something so simple, and I've spent hour on it.

---

There was no problem with the code itself. It was simply that my editor Sublime Text 3 didn't handle accepting user input well.

Comment: I just tried it in irb. `name` is getting set to whatever input i provide.

Comment: Does it work? Maybe my installation is bad.

Comment: Yes it works just fine.

Comment: i am using ruby 2.1.3

Comment: It worked for me... How do you run the script exactly? Is it in a file and your run ruby file.rb?

Comment: Yeah. It's a file

Comment: Neither cmd nor Sublime Text 3 are doing it for me. Irb executes it fine though.

Comment: I wasn't putting ".rb" when calling from cmd. Sublime Text 3 doesn't run it. And I use it for my Ruby development.

Comment: I wasn't putting ".rb" when calling file from cmd.

Comment: ok so everything works. You can either delete this question or post an answer yourself. Or ask Ninigi to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: Yeah. Do you know why Sublime Text 3 doesn't run it though?

Comment: @Ninigi Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: For ruby files typing <CTRL+B> normally runs them. I got so used to it, that I assumed tge problem was with my code when the script didn't work

Comment: ahh ok, I didn't know that- apologies. Well, I guess someone else may know the answer.

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/11410158/5101493

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to make scripts run from command line:

1. Create a file ending in ".rb", for example "my_script.rb"
2. Run `ruby my_script.rb`
3. Don't forget ".rb" ;)

Comment: @user1934428 you are right, you do not HAVE to use the file extension, but it's convention to use .rb for Ruby files and most editors will rely on the file extension to determine the Language used. If you use .rb for the file name, then you must use it in the ```ruby file_name.rb``` command :>

Comment: I personally don't like having the programs I'm going to call from the commandline having any extension. After all, from the user's point of view, it doesn't matter what language a program is written in, and it happened to me more than once, that, for instance, a Perl or Ruby program was replaced by a shell script cover program, and we don't want to edit all the places the program is being called, just because the name changed. I do however name those Ruby files by .rb, which are not called directly, but only `require`-ed.

Comment: @user1934428 well, in that case I think you should consider using some shell scripts to execute your files right from the start. From the users point of view, it already DOES matter what language the script is in, or he could not execute it, so naming it cannonically would actually HELP the user to identify the language at first glance. Feel free to name your files whatever you like, in my oppinion it is always better to follow the naming convention though.